# tinyMCE - limit  RemoveFormat to a list of formats

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Current tinyMCE version (3.5.2).

Hi,

I am working on a custom plugin which adds and removes [custom formats](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_formats.php).

Adding a format to the current selection is simple however I couldn't
find a fitting solution for removing multiple formats.

What I did find was the RemoveFormat command:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('RemoveFormat');
// which is the same as 
tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.remove('removeformat');
```

This function does remove any formats of the current selection
and that is definitely to much as I want to remove only some of the formats.

So I tried to call the `remove` method for every format

```
tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.remove('format_1');
tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.remove('format_2');
...
```

However this wasn't successful either as it doesn't remove nested formats.
If you select the following paragraph and call `tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.remove('format_2');` it will **NOT** remove the format as the paragraph doesn't use this format itself.

```
<p class="format_1">abcd<span class="format_2>ef</span>g</p>
```

Is there any way to **remove a format of an element and also of all of its children** like RemoveFormat?

---

Update (@Thariama)

All my formats are custom formats with the following structure:

```
  "demo_format_1" : { 
      "classes" : "demo_format_1",
      "deep" : true,
      "exact" : false,
      "inline" : "span",
      "selector" : "*",
      "title" : "Demo Format"
   }}
```

---

Update:

After implementing this again I found further cases.
Here are examples of all special cases which came to my mind:

Text before removing the format:

```
<p>abc<span class=demo_format_1>def</span></p>
```

Case 1 (Covered with the so Jeffery To)

Selecting the whole paragraph should give you the following result

```
 <p>abcdef</p>
```

Case 2

Selecting only f should give you the following result

```
<p>abc<span class=demo_format_1>de</span>f</p>
```

Case 3

Selecting only cd should give you the following result

```
<p>abcd<span class=demo_format_1>ef</span></p>
```

Comment: are you using inline styles using spans or html-tags for bold, italic, underline?

Comment: @Thariama: I am using inline spans with classes. (See my updated question for details)

Comment: where and when do you call "tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.remove('removeformat');
"? are you using an own plugin?

Comment: Yes it it called by a custom plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[tinymce.Formatter.remove](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Formatter.remove) can be called on a specific node, so:

```
var selection = ed.selection.getSel(),
    ancestor = ed.selection.getNode(),
    els = ancestor.getElementsByTagName('span'),
    l = els.length,
    i = 0;
if (selection.containsNode(ancestor, true) && ancestor.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'span') {
    ed.formatter.remove('demo_format_2', null, ancestor);
}
for ( ; i < l; i++) {
    if (selection.containsNode(els[i], true)) {
        ed.formatter.remove('demo_format_2', null, els[i]);
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/82BRe/)

---

**Update:** Turns out the trouble is caused by including both `inline` and `selector` in the format, which marks it as "mixed" (inline + block level). If you define the format with only `inline`:

```
demo_format_1: {
    inline: "span",
    classes: "demo_format_1"
}
```

then `formatter.remove('demo_format_1')` works as you'd expect ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/82BRe/2/)).

Comment: Unfortunately it does only work for one case but not for all which removeFormat covers.

Comment: Thanks Jeffery! I will give you feedback in a minute.

Comment: Thanks Jeffery - I got a new bug now for apply formats but removing works.

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following:

1. get all paragaphs touched by the user selection
2. get all nodes under those paragraphs
3. check if a node is touched by the selection range
4. if it is: remove the 'unwanted' class from its class element

I will provide some code for this later.

Comment: I tried this however if you apply and remove the format several times the result code has a lot of "empty" spans: `<p><span><span><span>text</span></span</span></p>`

Comment: looks like you need to check for empty spans and delete them afterwards: 1. find such spans and delete them 2. go up throught the chain of parent nodes of such spans and check if they are empty (if yes delete them and so on, you may stop if a span or parentNode is not empty). This won't however solve the nested span problem. Best thing would be to avoid nesting of spans.

Comment: another (this time working) approch to get rid of all those unwanted spans would be to check for every span (in the former selection or whole editor) if it is the only child of its parentNode and in this case set the spans innerHTML to the spans parentNode: span.parentNode.innerHTML = span.innerHTML;

Comment: That sounds good - to bad that you have to write it all by yourself instead of using a tinyMCE function.

Comment: Unfortunatly, yes. I even have been able to prevent tinymce to nest spans, but it was pretty complicated and i had to overwrite the default Formatter class.

Comment: if i can help you with code - let me know (i already have developed many tinymce plugins)