# TinyMCE: adding a shorcut

Tags: javascript, tinymce, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to be able to use the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to remove the format in a `TinyMCE` editor. Among others, I have followed the answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916776/how-do-i-implement-tinymce-shortcuts-in-tinymce-v4) an that [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054324/tinymce-limit-removeformat-to-a-list-of-formats).

I have tried:

```
tinymce.init({
    body_id: "zotero-tinymce-note",
    content_css: "css/note-content.css",

    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.shortcuts.add('ctrl+Space', function(){      
            tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('RemoveFormat');
            //tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.remove('removeformat');
            });
        },
    plugins: //some code,
    toolbar1: //some code,
});
```

I also tried this setup:

```
setup: function(e) {
        e.on("keyup", function(e) {
            if ( e.keyCode == 32 && e.ctrlKey) {  
                tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('RemoveFormat');
            }
        });
},
```

I also tried to replace

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('RemoveFormat');
```

by

```
tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.remove('removeformat');
```

But no matter which combination I do, nothing happens when I select a text and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. I don't know if this is relevant, but I would like to implement this shortcut in the `TinyMCE` editor of [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the description parameter:

```
editor.shortcuts.add('ctrl+a', 'remove formatter', function(){      
    tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('RemoveFormat');
});
```

ctrl+space however does not seem to work, it is considered ctrl+s. To fix it, you can use the charcode directly:

```
editor.shortcuts.add('ctrl+32', 'remove formatter', function(){      
    tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('RemoveFormat');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, your code is working on a simple TinyMCE editor but not in 
 the editor loaded in Zotero. Any idea, how I can bypass what Zotero is blocking in some way?

Comment: is setup function running?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I don't know, how can I check that?

Comment: I don't think so, I don't get any alert box like i do on a simple TinyMce editor. So I guess setup function doesn't work

Comment: what version of tinymce zotero uses?

Comment: It's  the version TinyMce 4

Comment: would need to see your full html

Comment: Well, it doesn´t work because setup is already declared below. Add the 3 lines of code below zoteroInit(ed); and change editor for ed

Comment: Thanks for your patience. It's working! Super! It's really kind of your to help me untill it worked!